# Opencv module is imported in conda and VS Code but Not IDLE & Libs aren't imported in VsCode and IDLE

Tags: python, opencv, visual-studio-code, terminal, path

*The OpenCV module runs without errors in Vs code, Spyder
But it runs with errors in python IDEL And doesn't import Libs
When I open The terminal of all these editors 
Vscode terminal doesn't import Libs
Python IDEL doesn't import libs
Anaconda Prompt imports Libs*

So My Error is
**What's the problem with python IDEL and VS code terminal?
And how can I solve this?**

```
#VS CODE
import cv2
from os import path
video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
xml_classifier = path.join(path.dirname(cv2.__file__),
                           "data", "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")
while True:
    grabbed, frame = video.read()
    frame = cv2.resize(frame, (800, 500))

    def detect_faces(frame):
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        face_calssifier = cv2.CascadeClassifier(xml_classifier)
        rects = face_calssifier.detectMultiScale(gray,
                                                 scaleFactor=1.15,
                                                 minNeighbors=5,
                                                 minSize=(30, 30))
        return rects

    def draw(frame, rects, title):  # , text):
        print("=" * 30)
        print("i found {} people.".format(len(rects)).title())
        print("=" * 30)

        for x, y, w, h in rects:
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

        if title:
            cv2.imshow(title, frame)
    draw(frame, detect_faces(frame), "Video")
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
video.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

### In Vs code terminal ---------------------------------------------------------------------

PS C:\Users\ASUS> & C:/Users/ASUS/Anaconda3/Anaconda/python.exe c:/Users/ASUS/Computer-Vision-Projects/FDVW.py
==============================
I Found 1 People.
==============================
==============================
I Found 1 People.
==============================
==============================
I Found 1 People.
==============================
==============================
I Found 1 People.
==============================
==============================
I Found 1 People.
==============================
[ WARN:0] global C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (674) SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback
PS C:\Users\ASUS> python
Python 3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 17:00:18) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
>>> import flask
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
>>> import os
>>>
```

```
# In python Idle
Python 3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 17:00:18) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import cv2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
>>> import flask
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    import flask
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'
>>> import os
>>>
=== RESTART: C:\Users\ASUS\Computer-Vision-Projects\#01_face_detection.py ===
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\Computer-Vision-Projects\#01_face_detection.py", line 1, in <module>
    import cv2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
>>>
```

But In Anaconda prompt it runs without errors and import libs And Spyder runs without errors

```
(base) C:\Windows\system32>python
Python 3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Mar 29 2018, 13:32:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
>>> import flask
>>> import numpy
>>> import os
```

> The Same error in opencv is be in flask, numpy and etc.
>   The python path in Vs code settings:
>   "python.pythonPath": "C:\Users\ASUS\Anaconda3\Anaconda\python",

My VSCode settings

```
    {

        "editor.fontSize": 22,
        "editor.rulers": [80],
        "editor.fontWeight": "500",
        "debug.console.fontSize": 16,
        "terminal.integrated.fontSize": 16,
        "terminal.integrated.fontWeight": "100",
        // "files.autoSaveDelay": 500,
        "files.autoSave": "onFocusChange",
        "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",

        "terminal.integrated.shell.linux": "/usr/bin/zsh",
        // "terminal.integrated.inheritEnv": false,

        //? linux
        // "python.pythonPath": "/usr/bin/python3.8",

        //? py36
        "python.pythonPath": "C:\\Users\\ASUS\\Anaconda3\\Anaconda",

        "python.formatting.provider": "autopep8",
        "[python]": {
          "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.python"
        },
        "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
          "terminal.foreground": "#f0a212",
          "terminal.background": "#161C28",
          // "terminal.background": "#232F34",
          "tab.activeBorder": "#02e039",
          // "activityBar.activeBackground":"#1684b3a9",
          "activityBar.activeBorder": "#02e039",
          // "list.inactiveSelectionBackground": "#86a9fb",
          "statusBar.background": "#333",
          "statusBar.foreground": "#fff",
          "statusBar.noFolderBackground": "#333",
          "statusBar.noFolderForeground": "#fff"
        },
        "gotoNextPreviousMember.symbolKinds": ["function"],
        "editor.formatOnSave": true,
        "editor.showFoldingControls": "mouseover",
        "python.jediEnabled": false,
        // "workbench.statusBar.feedback.visible": false,
        "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
        "workbench.settings.editor": "json",

        //!READ THIS ARTICLE TO CUSTOMIZE THE TERMINAL
        //? https://pascalnaber.wordpress.com/2019/10/05/have-a-great-looking-terminal-and-a-more-effective-shell-with-oh-my-zsh-on-wsl-2-using-windows/
        "terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "Source Code Pro Semibold",
        "terminal.integrated.cursorStyle": "line",
        "terminal.integrated.cursorBlinking": true,
        "workbench.startupEditor": "newUntitledFile",
        "git.autofetch": true,
        "workbench.list.openMode": "singleClick",
        "zenMode.hideLineNumbers": false,
        "zenMode.hideTabs": false,
        "workbench.activityBar.visible": true,
        "git.enableSmartCommit": true,
        "window.zoomLevel": -1,
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.python",
        // "terminal.integrated.rendererType": "dom",
        "sync.autoUpload": true,
        "sync.forceUpload": true,
        "sync.gist": "13d7fc3f673defc7dc0cba7f7d3dd8a5",
        "workbench.colorTheme": "Newton (rainglow)",
        "kite.showWelcomeNotificationOnStartup": false,
        "extensions.ignoreRecommendations": false,
        "python.dataScience.sendSelectionToInteractiveWindow": true,
        "vsicons.dontShowNewVersionMessage": true,
        "editor.columnSelection": false,
        "dart.debugExternalLibraries": true,
        "dart.debugSdkLibraries": false,
        "dart.previewHotReloadOnSaveWatcher": true,
        "editor.multiCursorModifier": "alt",
        "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
        "[dart]": {
          "editor.tabSize": 4,
          "editor.insertSpaces": false,
          "editor.formatOnSave": true
        },
        "python.linting.enabled": true,
        "editor.tabSize": 4,

        //!############################################################

        "window.titleBarStyle": "custom",
        "window.enableMenuBarMnemonics": false,
        "window.customMenuBarAltFocus": false,
        //!############################################################
      }
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solve this error By open anaconda prompt and open your python path like`cd C:\Program Files\Python36` And write `python -m pip uninstall --user opencv-contrib-python` if you have this error "No module named pip.**main**; 'pip' is a package and cannot be directly executed" write this `python get-pip.py`if you don't have get-pip.py download it from https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py Save it in your python path .
After All this run `python -m pip install --user opencv-contrib-python`. Make the same thing with numpy and flask. import these libs in Vs code Terminal, Anaconda prompt and python IDLE.

Answer (score 0):

[image: After My Solution]

After My Answer I can import any lib I added it in python by this way so upvote answer if it solved your error and helped you